# Adding elements to the layer tree view?

Tags: pyqgis

Is there a way to add custom elements (checkboxes, or more ...) or change some elements properties (colours ?) in the **genuine** layer tree view of QGIS using PyQgis?

Comment: If you can add more details to your question, it will be easier to give you a hand. Where exactly would you like to add a checkbox for a layer?  For example, you could add a screenshot.  Otherwise, I consider the question a bit unclear.